# Is there a Non Directional Beacon(NDB) morse code sound database?

Tags: navigation, radio-communications

I need to know what is the morse code sound of:

CALL: OZ
Khz: 212
QTH: RUCKR
lat: 31.2292
long:-85.7917

I found this website, but I could not find the sound of different NDBs:
http://classaxe.com/dx/ndb/rna

Comment: You can useText-to-Audio Morse generators. [Random one](https://morsecode.scphillips.com/trainer.html): use free text at the end of the page and enter the call sign, here "oz", You can get the corresponding .wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a [website](http://www.ve3gop.com/sounds.html) that has some NDB sounds that can give you examples of what an NDB sounds like.

Basically each NDB transmits a one, two, or three letter identification.

On the chart, you can tell what to listen to by looking at the dots and dashes next to the identifier. In the example below, Chualar is UAD

```
..-
.-
-..
```

[image: ndb]

Comment: Thank you. I found OZ, 212 in this website https://skyvector.com/